# Check how many users visited particular site

Tags: 2013, site-collection, publishing-site, site-usage

I have a SP site collection which hosts internal team portal. Template that was used for it is a publishing site.

I want to check how many users visited site. I know there is an **Usage Report** in
**Site Settings** > **Popularity and Search Reports** where I can usually check for what I need.
 But only on this site collection I have all zeros instead of actual numbers. On every other site collection it is ok.
I checked in CA, **Manage web applications** > **Service Connections** and there **Usage and Health data collections** is checked.
Also appropriate site collection and site features are enabled.
All jobs are running smoothly.

*edit:*
Now, what a colleague of mine found is that Usage report ran smoothly until someone switched address from **http** to **https**. We found reports in sql from time url was http.
But in CA, url of web application still says it is http and port is 80, but when I check in address bar it is https.

Is it possible something went wrong with this address switch or if you have any idea where or what should I look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.
In **Site settings**, under **Site Administration**, choose **Popularity Trends**.
There I found same as for site collection excel **Usage reports** document.

Answer (score 0):

Reporting - site collection feature

SharePoint Server Standard Site features - site feature

are this feature activated ?

Comment: yes, they are already enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing Timer Job is running?

You could check the timer job status from CA -> Monitoring -> Review Job Definitions. If it is not enabled yet, try to enable it and set the schedule.

Comment: I don't see job with that name anywhere. Not even disabled.

Comment: You could get them back using powershell: (Get-SPUsageService).Provision()